# XFree86-Mesa-libGL , XFree86-libs

Tags: command-line, package-management, lubuntu

I'm new to Linux and today I'm trying to install AMD Catalyst™ 15.9 Proprietary Linux Graphics Driver for my HD 7650M.

Everything so far is good, but when I try to install XFree86-Mesa-libGL and XFree86-libs in terminal via `sudo apt install XFree86-Mesa-libGL XFree86-libs` it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package XFree86-Mesa-libGL
E: Unable to locate package XFree86-libs
```

Any ideas how I can install these packages?

Comment: There are no such packages in Ubuntu. From where did you get the instructions to install them? Package names are always lower-case in Ubuntu (and Debian).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Unless I'm mistaken I believe the instructions were found [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst15-9LINReleaseNotes.aspx)